# Use of dynamic paint to influence transform settings

Tags: particles, drivers, dynamic-paint

Can Dynamic Paint be used as a factor for a driver?
I want to automaticly shake an object when hit by, for example a particle. The easiest way to register an impact accuratly seams to be dynamic paint. Is it possible to use the output, into for example a vertex group, to influence the, for example, transform behaviour?
If there is a better way, please let me know.